# Elementor: How to add field value to webhook?

Tags: webhooks, elementor

How to add contact_phone field value to Elementor Pro Form widget webhook url?

I tried:

```
contact_phone
[contact_phone]
[field id="contact_phone"]
array["fields"]["contact_phone"]["value"]
```

at email templates "[field id="contact_phone"]" works fine. But all my attempts at webhook were like plain text, not field value.

```
form name: contact_form
field id/name: contact_phone
webhook: https://***.intrumnet.com/onlineforms?action=fillform&formtype=9&data[def_customer][phone]=array["fields"]["contact_phone"]["value"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear to me the exact URL of your webhook, but please try this and adjust if needed.

- in the form's actions after submit, include a redirect
- for the redirect URL enter `webhookURL/?contact_phone=[field id="contact_phone"]`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else finds this post (as I did) when searching for a similar issue, here's the answer to this post:

Copy the shortcode from the field in Elementor Forms - it will look something like this: [field id="first_name"]

Use that to construct the webhook url. My webhook url that's working fine looks like this:

```
https://example.com/webhook.php?first_name=[field id="first_name"]&last_name=[field id="last_name"]&email=[field id="email"]&phone_number=[field id="phone_number"]&utm_source=[field id="utm_source"]&utm_medium=[field id="utm_medium"]&utm_campaign=[field id="utm_campaign"]&utm_term=[field id="utm_term"]&remote_ip=[field id="remote_ip"]&gclid=[field id="gclid"]
```

This works great, until you keep having to edit every form on your sites when you want to start collecting a new parameter! I keep searching for a way to make Elementor just add every parameter and value it finds in the current url to the webhook url. It doesn't seem possible.